# Does mounting an NFS drive take up space in the NFS client?

Tags: storage, nfs

I follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04) to setup NFS for my server. Currently I have 1 server which share part of it directories as the **HOST**, 2 server that mounts these directories as the **CLIENT**.

My question is very straight forward, if my **HOST** contain 2 million picture which used about 100GB storage, does the **CLIENT** who mount the folder of the **HOST** also took 100GB storage? Or only **HOST** took those storage **CLIENT** just read and write but never took space in the **CLIENT** server?

I know it might be a stupid question but it is a good start if someone help me understading the concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: no. You're mounting a remote drive, but you're not syncing all the remote data to a local disk.